# Incorrect dates in Chartkick

Tags: ruby, chartkick

Chartkick gem is placing values one day behind the data input.

```
{Tue, 15 Jul 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>1, Wed, 16 Jul 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>0, Thu, 17 Jul 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>0, Fri, 18 Jul 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>0, Sat, 19 Jul 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>0, Sun, 20 Jul 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>0, Mon, 21 Jul 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>5}
```

The first point on the line chart is labeled as the 14th and the last is 20th??

I have double checked the date on the system and to make sure I am sending the correct data and it all looks correct. The above data set is directly from the html on the page.

Comment: Are you using Rails with `config.time_zone` set to something other than 'UTC'?  If so, Rails is converting the times to time zone you've configured.

Comment: application.rb has  config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
Time.zone.name => "UTC"

Comment: Based on this charkick issue (https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/91), it is probably converting the values from UTC to your local time zone.

Comment: you are a scholar and a gentleman, adding a format with discrete fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with my area_chart, and followed the link from @Cisuuable answer. But to get the output to match the utc in the view I didn't have to pass discrete: true. I just worked with groupdate gem's format variable:

[groupdate gem info](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) Under the 'Pretty keys' heading

Which specified the format takes a string, which is passed to strftime, or a Proc. So i visited [strftime reference](http://www.strfti.me/)

To get my dates in the view back to utc i changed

```
<%= area_chart @visits.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>
```

to

```
<%= area_chart @visits.group_by_day(:created_at, format: "%B %d, %Y").count %>
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but in my case I'm seeing a time stamp (July 11, 2016 12:00:00 AM) in my production environment that I'm not seeing in my dev env (July 11, 2016). Any idea what would fix that? Thanks fro the help! I'm pleased it's the right day now.

Comment: You may need to adjust the time settings in your rails `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 1):

Hey i had the same problem and the answer was in [Associations with Chartkick & Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079683/associations-with-chartkick-rails) it was all about changing group_by_day to group as it is written in comment on that topic. Hope it helps